# .NET Core 6 identity multiple User Class

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi

I maintained an authentication based on a single class `User` using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` and
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` with code first approach.

Everything works perfectly and `User` claim their roles until I add the second class and their navigation properties.

The broker adds to the database but returns an error and JWT token doesn't have the role.
I'm getting this error :

> An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "melondb", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.

Here are my classes and their navigation properties :

```
namespace API.Entities
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public  List<Broker> Broker { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace API.Entities
{
    public class Broker: IdentityUser
    {
        public User Suprior { get; set; }
        public string SupriorId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is the DbContext

```
public class ProjectContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Broker> Brokers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
 
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
               .HasData(
                        new IdentityRole { Name = "Member", NormalizedName = "MEMBER" },
                        new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
                        new IdentityRole { Name = "Broker", NormalizedName = "BROKER" }
               );

        builder.Entity<User>(e =>
                {
                    e.HasMany(p => p.Broker)
                     .WithOne(p => p.Suprior)
                     .HasForeignKey(p => p.SupriorId);  
                });
        builder.Entity<Broker>(e =>
                {
                   e.HasOne(p => p.Suprior)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Broker)
                    .HasForeignKey(p => p.SupriorId); 
                });
    }
}
```

This is my `Program.cs` after adding second class

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
{
    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
}
)
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<Broker>(opt =>
{
    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectContext>();

ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
        {
            opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWTSettings:TokenKey"]))
            };
        });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenServiceBroker>();

var app = builder.Build();
using var scop = app.Services.CreateScope();
var context = scop.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ProjectContext>();
var userManager = scop.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
var brokerManager = scop.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<Broker>>();
var logger = scop.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<WebApplication>>();

try
{
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
    await DbInitializer.Initialize(context, userManager, brokerManager);
...
```

This is the `BrokerController` where error occurred:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(BrokerRegisterDto registerDto)
{
    var broker = new Broker { UserName = registerDto.Username, Email = registerDto.Email, PhoneNumber = registerDto.PhoneNumber, SupriorId = registerDto.SupriorId };
    var result = await _brokerManager.CreateAsync(broker, registerDto.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(error.Code, error.Description);

        }

        return ValidationProblem();
    }

    await _brokerManager.AddToRoleAsync(broker, "Broker"); //this is the place where error occurred 
    return StatusCode(201);
}
```

also, I have separate TokenService for each Class

Comment: It would really help to show which part of the code throws the exception and maybe also to cut down the code you show to the essentials.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you for your advice, I made it cleaner and remove some extra codes. also I pointed the place where error occurred with comment in the code

Comment: It seems that two classes inheriting `IdentityUser` isn't possible. Why do you want that?

Comment: @GertArnold yes both classes were inherited from IdentityUser. I want a superior to be able to make accounts for brokers and brokers sign in separately.
superior can have a list of brokers and a broker can have only one superior. it's a many-to-one relationship.  is it possible this way?

Comment: As I often say: I would use the ASP.Net identity model as-is. Don't extend it. It mixes authenitcation/authorization concerns with business logic. Create a separate DbContext for the application and your own ApplicationUser class (or the like) that has a simple FK (not a reference property) to the identity user, then you can do with it whatever you like.